# Is it possible to make the ApplicationPoolIdentity attach a database with User Instance = true?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I use the "real" IIS 7.5 server in the development phase. The site points to the web project folder which contains `WebProjectDir\App_Data\database.mdf`.

The site runs under `ApplicationPoolIdentity` as follows:

[image]

When I run the application I get the following errors:

```
Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.

Source Error:

Line 14:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 15:         {
Line 16:             return View(db.Genres.ToList());
Line 17:         }
Line 18: 


Source File: G:\MvcMusicStore\Controllers\StoreController.cs    Line: 16
```

I can remove these errors by setting the application to run under `NetworkService`. However, I want to use `ApplicationPoolIdentiy` if it is possible with any adjustment. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dave, I found the solution yesterday.

Setting `Load User Profile` to `True` will make the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` able to attach the database.

[image]

Comment: This will only work for the standard Application Pools (DefaultAppPool and Classic .NET AppPool) as they are the only ones which have user profiles on disk. See http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/ for more details on user profiles for ApplicatoinPoolIdentity.

Answer (score 2):

That error relates to SQL Express.

Take a look at this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/527bf46a-b3fe-4ae6-8b41-eb40024399c8/

The problem is that any account that connects directly to an MDF file through SQL Express must have a local user profile.  If you have the full version of SQL Server running on that server (or another), you should be able to attach that MDF file as a database and connect that way.  Otherwise your application pool will have to run under an account that has a profile, like NETWORK SERVICE.

Comment: Is it possible to grant `ApplicationPoolIdentity` the same access to attach db as `NetworkService` can do?

Comment: If that user can log on locally, then yes.  If not, then it will never have a profile and therefore cannot be used in that way.  In any case, I wouldn't set it up that way even if you could make it work because I believe that user is restricted that way for security reasons.